# Resolving UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in express get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

trying to get my data after creating it in mongodb  from localhost:3000/todos/ and i get the error in node [UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client] i make use of the following

```
// Require Express
const express = require("express");

// Setting Express Routes
const router = express.Router();

// Set Up Models
const Todo = require("../models/todo");

// Get All Todos
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const todo = await Todo.find();
    res.json(todo);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});
```

this is my app.js with the necessary route to localhost:3000/todos/

```
// Require Express
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// Require Body-Parser
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// Require Cors
const cors = require("cors");

// Middlewares - [Set bodyParser before calling routes]
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Import Routes
const todoRoutes = require("./routes/todo");

// Setup Routes Middlewares
app.use("/", todoRoutes);
app.use("/todos", todoRoutes);
```

i want to see to see my output daata on localhost:3000/todos/ but i get it on localhost:3000/ . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok i got a hang of it and it was my routes causing it i just adjusted where the route was to be directed.

```
// Import Routes
const todoRoutes = require("./routes/todo");

// Setup Routes Middlewares
app.use("/todos", todoRoutes);
```